# Observable object vs ObservableArray and arrayFilter

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, observable

I am getting json data mapping a list to an observablearray via ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);

When the page loads the first item in the array is set to the selected via the following code.  As the user clicks on thumbnails i will grab that image/photo via ajax and put it into the images observableArray.  The goal here is to store locally each photo selected as the user clicks on it and when they click on that image again it checks the observablearray first to see if already loaded

```js
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
    

//set self.selected value to the first item in the array
self.selected = ko.observable(self.photos()[0]);

//initializing in page observableArray
self.images = ko.observableArray([]);

//putting already loaded first item into images
self.images.push(self.photos()[0]);
```

As the user clicks on a thumbnail i execute the following to see if the image is in the observable array.  If not found then do ajax to get from server otherwise just set the selected photo as the new self.selected

```js
//in array
var found = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.images(), function (item) {
    return item.photoId() == id;
});
if (found.length === 0) {

  var q = ko.mapping.toJSON({ id: id });
  GetData(url + '/GetPhotoClient', q,
   function (data) {
      if (data.success === true) {

      ko.mapping.fromJS(data.photoClient, {}, self.selected);
      self.selected(data.photoClient);
    
      //put recent photo into images
      self.images.push(ph);

  } else {
    alert(data.success);
  }
}
        , true);
} else {
    self.selected(ko.observable(found));
}
```

In the page I am using  to show image.

The confusion/problem is sometimes i have ot use selected().imageSource and other times selected.imageSource.

It seems that the value of found is an object not and observable object. I am missing some base concept here i believe.  i.e. why at some times i use selected().imageSource and other times it is selected.imageSource and why does the value of object equal an object not an observable object.

I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because when you are getting the client photo from the server you don't create an observable for that object `self.selected(data.photoClient);` while when you already have the photo you create an observable for the found object `self.selected(ko.observable(found));`.

By the way, you probably should take a look at ko.utils.unwrapObservable(obj) that abstracts the observable concept and always returns the value of the object.